# Space Syntax Toolkit - What do the abbreviations (i.e. INThh) stand for?

Tags: qgis-3, syntax

I cannot seem to find any information on the used abbreviations in the Space Syntax Toolkit, such as these:
[image]

Is there any documentation available on the used abbreviations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I responded [at github](https://github.com/SpaceGroupUCL/qgisSpaceSyntaxToolkit/issues/190#issuecomment-929100481), what you have there is the metrics calculated from depthmapX, as they are passed through [a replacement table](https://github.com/SpaceGroupUCL/qgisSpaceSyntaxToolkit/blob/d62e757d55ca00353d766fe9a7a21ba00f958a5d/esstoolkit/analysis/DepthmapEngine.py#L167). You can get the metrics by opening a map in depthmapX and carrying out axial analysis with all options selected and Line Length as the weighting column.

| depthmapX | toolkit |
| --- | --- |
| Ref | ref |
| Choice | CH |
| Choice [Line Length Wgt] | CH[LEN] |
| Choice [Line Length Wgt][Norm] | CH[LEN]nor |
| Choice [Norm] | CHnorm |
| Connectivity | Conn |
| Control | control |
| Controllability | CONTR |
| Entropy | ENT |
| Harmonic Mean Depth | harMD |
| Integration [HH] | INThh |
| Integration [P-value] | INTpv |
| Integration [Tekl] | INTtk |
| Intensity | INTEN |
| Line Length | LEN |
| Mean Depth | MD |
| Mean Depth [Line Length Wgt] | MD[LEN] |
| Node Count | NC |
| RA | ra |
| RA [Penn] | ra[penn] |
| RRA | rra |
| Relativised Entropy | relNT |
| Total Depth | TD |
| Total Line Length | TLEN |

Comment: Thanks again for answering the question here, hope this helps others just as much as it did for me!